# Is there a way to increase the total number of service instances on Bluemix?

Tags: service, instance, ibm-cloud

According to Bluemix dashboard, total number of service instances I permitted to use is 4, but my colleagues' are 10. What cause this difference?

Is there a way to increase the total number of service instances on Bluemix?

Comment: This is off-topic here. This is internal user management, contact your administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will search and contact the administrator.

Comment: @KazuumiT. are you an IBMer?

Comment: I'm of an opinion that this is a good question ... the question asks about the user's Bluemix environment in which he wants to work and Bluemux is as much a remote environment as anything else ... that's the nature of a "Cloud" environment.

As for an actual answer, I don't know ... but it might be that your userid is associated with one contract while your colleagues is associated with a different contract.

Comment: Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of service instances depends on your org quota.

Type `cf quotas` in terminal to find out quotas available.

`cf org your-org-name` would show your current quota.

It sounds like your are on Trial, Check with your colleague on how he got more quota than yours.

If you think that you are assigned incorrect quota , please contact Bluemix project office team to investigate the discrepancy   : http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport --> **Select ID+Login**

**cf tool** can be downloaded from here : https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#downloads

Comment: Thanks for answering. I confirmed my quota, and it shows: "1024M memory limit, 100 routes, 4 services, paid services allowed." I will contact Bluemix project office team. By the way, my colleagues also don't know how they got more quota than me. It is not clear whether it is relevant with this difference, but as far as we know, people who registered and began to use Bluemix in August 2015 or later have the quota named "q2GB" (10 service instances at the maximum), and the other people like me who had been used Bluemix from earlier have less quota (1GB, 4 service instances at the max).

Comment: There might have been a policy change on how Bluemix allocates Trial Quota. Project Office can help you to sort it out.

Comment: Until yesterday, I got three answers from Bluemix project office. I am glad the additional quota. Now, I can make the application without having to remove the existing artifacts. Thank you very much!